# Safe load/store 64 bit operations on 32 bit instances

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, atomic

In Redis I use an header file called [atomicvar.h](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/atomicvar.h) which implements thread-safe atomic operations on integers, using different facilities depending on the compiler (and version) used. Currently there are three different implementations based on:

- __sync builtins, like __sync_add_and_fetch and similar.
- __atomic builtins, like __atomic_add_fetch
- pthread mutexes if none of the above is available

However as Redis moves more into threading, I need to do more than this header provides. For instance I need to store a 64 bit value safely (even if Redis is compiled with `-m32` with a 32 bit target).

While __atomic provides load/store operations, __sync apparently does not have this, even if it performs more complex operations like fetch and and, fetch and add, and so forth, there is not a trivial fetch_and_store, apparently.

The best thing I found so far is to use the following to implement a safe 64 bit store:

```
while(!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&var,var,new_value));
```

This is clearly an overkill since I don't want a check-and-set operation, I just want to write the value in a way that make me sure that other threads will not read an "half value", like the first 32 bits of the previous value and the next 32 bits of the new value.

Am I missing something or the above is really the best solution?

Currently, I cannot use C11 _Atomic, at least for 4.0 (but I'll switch in the future) because still very popular Linux distributions have GCC versions that do not support C11.

For reading I currently use:

```
__sync_add_and_fetch(&var,0);
```

While not perfect (useless zero addition) at least this does not need a loop.

Comment: I wonder if `while(!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&var,var,new_value));` behaves as expected on x86-32. This appears to use `CMPXCHG8B` under the hood, and the doc for it say: "To simplify the interface to the processor’s bus, the destination operand receives a write cycle without regard to the result of the comparison. "

Comment: @FrederikDeweerdt apparently it works as expected, see for example this code: https://gist.github.com/antirez/b01d38db02a0bac3b2b4328411449c37 Compiled with -m32 it produces code that never shows a race.

Comment: p.s. note that I'm using __sync_bool_compare_and_swap() here only to perform an atomic set and not a lock, so basically if the write happens *regardless* of the comparision, is the same from my POV as I just want a safe 64-bit store.

Comment: @FrederikDeweerdt That is why the compiler issues this instruction with a `lock` prefix; to make it an atomic operation

Comment: /me nods. I was wondering if the doc could mean that a partial write could leak. It does appear to mean that an atomic 64bit write happens no matter what the comparison results are.